# Change custom infix operation to compile to something else

Tags: raku

```
use Something;

sub infix:<%%%>(*@args) is assoc("list") { [*] @args }

say 9 %%% 10;
say 9 %%% 10 %%% -44;
```

i want to change it so that this compiles to `28 %%% 5` for first and `28 %%% 5 %%% -22` for second because if operand is odd, it is 3*$_+1 instead. if operand is even number, it is halved instead. What should I do in `use Something` to make this work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Riddle. When is half an answer already an answer? Answer: when you double it by doing nothing. Ain't that Something?

## The initial examples without `Something`

```
sub infix:<%%%>(*@args) is assoc("list") { [*] @args }

say 9 %%% 10;         # 90
say 9 %%% 10 %%% -44; # -3960
```

The goal is to introduce `Something` such that the output for the above (`90` and `-3960`) change to be output below (`140` and `-3080`):

```
say 28 %%% 5;         # 140
say 28 %%% 5 %%% -22; # -3080
```

We don't care about that second example from here on, just getting those two numbers output for the first example.

## First attempt at something. Half an answer?

Introduce a custom infix `*` and make it `oddeven` its arguments. Stick it at the top of the file to test (we can pop it in module later):

```
# use Something;

sub oddeven ($_) { $_ %% 2 ?? $_/2 !! &CORE::infix:<*>(3,$_) + 1 }

sub infix:<*>(*@args) is assoc<right> { &CORE::infix:<*>( |@args>>.&oddeven ) }

# Your original code:

sub infix:<%%%>(*@args) is assoc("list") { [*] @args }

say 9 %%% 10;         # 140
say 9 %%% 10 %%% -44; # -1540
```

The `-1540` is half what it should be. `&oddeven` is obviously being eval'd twice on the middle argument. Hmm.

## An answer? Do nothing, half the time.

Introduce a `noop` role (trait) and use appropriately:

```
role noop {}

multi oddeven (noop $_) { $_ }
multi oddeven (     $_) { $_ %% 2 ?? $_/2 !! &CORE::infix:<*>(3,$_) + 1 }

sub infix:<*>(*@args) is assoc<right> { &CORE::infix:<*>( |@args>>.&oddeven ) but noop }

sub infix:<%%%>(*@args) is assoc("list") { [*] @args }

say 9 %%% 10;         # 140
say 9 %%% 10 %%% -44; # -3080
```

- Declare a `noop` role that does... nothing.
- Split `oddeven` to do nothing with a `noop` argument.
- Add a `noop` tag to the value calculated by my custom infix `*` so `oddeven` would leave it alone when it gets called on that value a second time, as happens in a chained expression (the value that starts out as `10` in `9 %%% 10 %%% -22`).

I'll leave popping it into a module as an exercise for the reader.

## Problem solved?

That depends on the nature of the X in what is presumably [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I deliberately chose not to explore what you were really after (`X`), and instead focused on problem `Y`, the one you literally asked.

I've come up with *an* answer, but, but ... `but`. Also, I'm tired, so I haven't explained some of the code that maybe needs an explanation. So maybe this isn't yet an acceptable answer. If not, let's talk, but it won't be tonight.

Comment: I didn't know about the XY problem. And I find it so often among my students' questions. Thanks!

Comment: thanks. i presented very badly the question. i can also do `[*] @args.map({ $_ %% 2 ?? $_ / 2 !! 3*$_ + 1})` for the question. my main issue was with Whatever arguments because they turn into code objects. Like `* %%% 5` is code instead of call to my custom infix with Whatever. very sorry to cost time of you. should i edit qeuestion to add that example or should i accept this answer and ask another question

Comment: @freddy Thank you for commenting, and the challenge in your original Q, which I enjoyed. :) The main challenge of this question was figuring out how to leave your code entirely unchanged, so that the `Something` could be a module. But if it's about `Whatever` arguments/lambdas, then that's an entirely different issue. So, yes, please accept this answer, and then post another one. Thanks!

Comment: @freddy BTW, `* %%% 5` is turned into a code object that calls your custom infix operator. Which you can then call. So you can write `(9 %%% *)(10)` to get the same as `9 %%% 10`. Maybe that's all you need to know? Anyhow, play around with it for a few minutes. If for now everything seems to makes sense again, PLMK in a comment below. But if you find yourself confused about anything, after playing or at any time in the future, please consider posting another SO, and if you do, thank you in advance for doing so. :)

Comment: thanks many times im about to post another question because i literally want if possible to pass literally Whatever to infix